# Calculating Delay Time And Total Animation Time using IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am creating an animation from set of images and converting them to a gif file. I just have FPS supplied by user like 30fps how to calculate the delay time for creating a gif image using kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime and the total render time which is used in imageview. AnimationDuration  my code till now is as follows. For animating images :

```
imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
imageview.animationImages=arrImages;
imageview.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
prog=float prog=((1/slide.value)*totalimgcount);
imageview.animationDuration = prog;
imageview.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[imageview startAnimating];
```

For creating Gif File

```
imgData         = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
CGImageDestinationRef dest=CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef) imgData, kUTTypeGIF,
[arrImages count],
NULL);




NSDictionary *frameProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1/slide.value] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime]
                                                            forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];
NSDictionary *gifProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount]
                                                          forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];

for (UIImage *img in arrImages) {
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, img.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);

}
CGImageDestinationSetProperties(dest, (CFDictionaryRef)gifProperties);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest);
CFRelease(dest);
```

Please Help the animation that is rendered in the iphone is very fast and the gif that is created is very slow ......

Answer (score 0):

The image view duration is measured in seconds, whereas the gif delay is measured in hundredths of seconds, so you can't use exactly the same calculation and get exactly the same result in both situations.

Comment: but any algorith with some difference would even go but here in my algorithm everything is running very slow or very fast in the other end....

Comment: Based on your current code I would expect the speeds to be 100 times different. Try [NSNumber numberWithInt:100/slide.value]